# gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name

Tags: ros, installation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I am following the [installation guide for Debian Buster of ROS Noetic](http://wiki.ros.org/noetic/Installation/Debian) and in the second step, executing the comand `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654` I got the following error:

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.nAyAX9Bj38/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkp://ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 --recv-key C1CF6E31E6BADE8868B172B4F42ED6FBAB17C654
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No name
```

I read that apt-key is deprecated or something like that. How can I continue the installation?

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391118/gpg:-keyserver-receive-failed:-no-name/) by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2021-11-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-17**:
There is a recent similar question, please take a look: https://answers.ros.org/question/307081/unable-to-install-keys-for-ros-kinetic-using-ubuntu-1604/

**Comment by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) on 2021-11-17**:
Thank you a lot for your comment. I think I have resolved it by other way.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-11-17**:
Glad you found an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

Trying other ways to solve it, I finally solved it using the command:

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then following the rest of the steps it works fine, but for example It is not available:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full
```

Instead I have used:

```
sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop
```

And it is installing.

Best regards.
Alessandro

---

Originally posted by [Alessandro Melino](https://answers.ros.org/users/52370/alessandro-melino/) with karma: 113 on 2021-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0